# Simple example of displaying an image fullscreen in Python

Tags: python, linux

I'd like to display (and change/update) an image full screen on Linux using Python. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is popular image library for python. Thus I would recommend starting from it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [TKinter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html) or [PyGame](http://www.pygame.org/news.html) to show images and draw objects over them to change them.

Example using TKinter:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width =1224,height=1000)
logo=PhotoImage(file="myimage.jpg")
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=logo) #Change 0, 0 to whichever coordinates you need
root.mainloop()
```

Example using PyGame:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
WIDTH = 1280
HEIGHT = 1080
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT), 0, 32)
img = pygame.image.load("myimage.jpg")
while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        windowSurface.blit(img, (0, 0)) #Replace (0, 0) with desired coordinates
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: the Tkinter example doesn't do anything for me... I run this and all I get is a small window with no image, would you know why?

Comment: That would be because you do not have an image `myimage.jpg` in the directory where you are running this code. Just add an image to the directory, and change `myimage.jpg` to the name of the desired image.

Comment: hm... I think I had done that... I've gone off though using PyQt4 to achieve what I want, Thank you!

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help :)

Comment: By the way, PyGame is also very powerful, but PyQt4 is a good choice too.

Comment: I've checked PyGame out a few times but have never used it, always seems to be throwing me off for some reason... Need to check it out at some point in the future though! Thanks again

Comment: :) feel free to ask me any question about pygame, and I will do my best to help!

Comment: This renders the image transposed for me.

Comment: @A.J.Uppal This is technically fullscreen, but only for a specific resolution. Can you do it dynamically for the screen resolution?

Comment: Is there any way to plot the image on the entire screen, without showing bars or whatever?